# How does linking Spotify to Uber effect the Uber experience?

Tags: spotify

After connecting Spotify will I hear music I like, or that Spotify recommends for me, in the car?

What's the effect of this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify doesn't work unless you have *Spotify Premium*.

http://newsroom.uber.com/2014/11/uber-spotify-music-for-your-ride/

> Soundtracking your Uber ride is easy:
>
> 1. **Connect your Spotify account from the Uber Profile screen.** You only
>      need to do this once.
> 2. **Request a ride as usual in the Uber app**. If you
>      get matched with a music-enabled Uber, the music bar will appear at
>      the bottom of the Uber app.
> 3. **Tap the music bar and choose a song** from
>      any of your Spotify playlists while you wait for your Uber to arrive.
>
> Feel free to put your phone away; your playlist will start when your
>   ride begins. Sit back and enjoy, or be the backseat DJ and wirelessly
>   control the music from the Uber or Spotify app until you arrive at
>   your destination. You can even discover new music through Uber’s
>   featured playlists, specially curated to celebrate the city you ride
>   in.

I suppose if you do, it is supposed to show a music bar at the bottom of the Uber app that you can use to control the music. I think you can also use the Spotify app to control the music also.